# SQL Server help how to retrieve not NULL/Blank records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. Can anyone help how to retrieve the result with the requirement below?

Table **Customer**:

```
MemberID   Name     State      Active
----------------------------------------
-2000      John     Virginia     Y
-1999      Pearson  Texas   
-1998      David    Minnesota   NULL
-1997      Suraj    NewYork 
-1996      Brad     NewYork
```

Table **OrderPlacement**:

```
OrderID Memberid    Active    OrderlineNo   
-----------------------------------------
1       -2000                    1
2       -2000         Y          2
3       -1999        NULL        1
4       -1999        NULL        2
5       -1999         Y          3
6       -1998        NULL        1
7       -1998        NULL        2
8       -1998        NULL        3
9       -1997                    1
10      -1997                    2
11      -1997                    3
12      -1996                    1
13      -1996         N          2
```

Requirement: retrieve `Memberid` from  the `Customer` table where `Active` on `Customer` table is blank or `null` and the `Active` field is `null` or blank on  ALL the service line number records on the `OrderPlacement` table (If the `Active` field is populated for even single orderlineno on orderplacement for a memberid then it should not be retrieve selected).

Only `memberid` `-1997` and `-1998` should be retrieved.

My query:

```
SELECT c.memberid
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN Orderplacement op ON c.memberid = op.memberid
WHERE ISNULL(c.active, '') = ''
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT op1.memberid Orderplacement op1
                  WHERE (ISNULL(op1.active, '') <> ''))
```

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

what about this one?
It is near same as your with some fixes

```
SELECT c.memberid
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN Orderplacement op ON c.memberid = op.memberid
WHERE ISNULL(c.active, '') = ''
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Orderplacement op1
                  WHERE c.memberid = op1.memberid and (ISNULL(op1.active, '') <> ''))
```

you simply forgot about join(correlation) in your exists statement

Comment: This construct is called a *correlated subquery*.  The Op  forgot about the correlation condition.

Comment: One more question, how to get the exactly same result without using <>. Looks like its not preferred to use <>. Thanks